# React - if multiply one line

Tags: typescript, if-statement

I tried this if in my react project.

```
if (
  (role !== UserRoleEnum.Admin || role !== UserRoleEnum.Employee) &&
  (project.state === ProjectState.online || project.state === ProjectState.onhold)
) { }
```

I get this error back

> This condition will always return 'true' since the types
> 'UserRoleEnum.Admin' and 'UserRoleEnum.Employee' have no overlap.
> TS2367

How can i set this best up, that i got all in one if statement.

I want to check if

- user is not Admin or not Employee
  and
- project state is Online or OnHold

Comment: *"I want to check if user is Admin or Employee"* - Then you have a typo.  You're currently checking if user is **not** Admin or **not** Employee.  And the error is telling you that the user will **always** be **not** one of those.

Comment: Sorry I want to check if not Admin or if not Employee

Comment: In that case the error is correct.  That condition will *always* be true.  Why do you want that?

Comment: I have a return that only should show if project is online or onhold but not for admin user and for employees

Comment: It's Admin then it's not Employee, vice versa.. the error explains itself. Check back your requirement first.

Comment: @user1551496: So did you mean "not admin **and** not employee"?  The logic here keeps changing with every response.

Comment: No. I mean not admin OR not employee - Show check user and if he is not in one of these 2 role's show return

Comment: @user1551496: Then what you have, by design, is a condition which will *always* be true.  You can just follow the compiler's advice and remove that part of the condition entirely.  Make it: `if (project.state === ProjectState.online || project.state === ProjectState.onhold)`

Comment: ok - i got that point now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if the user is an Admin or an Employee, shouldn't you do something like this:

```
if ((role === UserRoleEnum.Admin) || (role === UserRoleEnum.Employee))
```

Notice that you were negating this comparison on your original code: `role !== UserRoleEnum.Admin`

This is probably why you got the compilation error, since the types don't seem to overlap, you will always receive a `true` on this comparison:

```
if ((role !== UserRoleEnum.Admin) || (role !== UserRoleEnum.Employee))
```

The only way you would get a `false` here would be if `Admin` and `Employee` have something in common that says that `role` can't be neither. Otherwise, when `role` is an `Admin` it is not an `Employee`, so you get `true` and when it is an `Employee` it is not an `Admin` and you also get `true`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if
>
> - user is not Admin or not Employee and
> - project state is Online or OnHold

The error message is specifically referring to the first condition in that set.  Unless it's possible for any given user to be both an Admin **and** an Employee (and the compiler is telling you that it is not) then that condition will *always* be `true`.  Every user in the system is always not at least one of those two things.

According to comments in the question, you have confirmed that this is *exactly* the logic you want:

> David: So did you mean "not admin and not employee"?
> user1551496: No. I mean not admin OR not employee

Since your intended condition is *always* true, you have two options:

1. Remove the condition entirely and just always execute the logic in that `if` block; or
2. Just remove the *first part* of the condition but still check the rest of it:

   ```
   if (project.state === ProjectState.online || project.state === ProjectState.onhold)
   { }
   ```